# Is it possible to hide applications in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, privacy

Maybe something where you need to enter a password to access hidden applications or something? (I'm pretty new to Linux)

Comment: A clearer usage example of who you wish to deny this knowledge from and why would be helpful. It is generally easier to deny permission to execute certain applications, harder to prevent their discovery some users.

Comment: I would like the application I'm trying to hide to only be useable on the root account and not standard accounts. My friends know the the password to be able to use sudo but not the password to get into my account. They have been trying to annoy me by transferring some of my applications to their accounts. For example one of them transferred steam to their account which was really annoying, which is why i want to hide some of my applications.

Comment: Use home directory encryption if you want to protect your steam stuff.

Comment: @Sol33t303 If it is clear they can't be trusted with access to your computer, why give it to them in the first place? Is there any reason to? I suggest you change your passwords and not share them with anyone. If, however, you think they can be trusted, then talk seriously with your friends about what they should and shouldn't do.

Comment: @SamuelSantana i guess it would be easier to probably do that, but they are my roomates and have been for a while. And they helped pay for the PC so yeah, it's a shared PC and it would drive me insane getting asked to put in the password everytime they want to install something. I trust them, they wouldn't do anything malicious, sometimes they just like messing with me. And honestly sometimes it's pretty funny.

Comment: @SamuelSantana this seems like a social problem. You have given admin access to untrustworthy people; Ubuntu cannot help you with that. Any software-based solution is merely a workaround, not a real solution. Put your private applications and data on a USB stick or a cloud site, so it's not on your computer at all. Or uninstall your private applications before logging out, and re-install them when logging in. There *are* complex solutions like you are looking for (ACLs, SELinux), but they are advanced and complex, require skills, and will promptly break your system if used unwisely.